# Send directly to printer with reporting services

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, reporting-services

I have this Reporting Services repository with some reports that accept Parameters via URL.

I want my application to send these reports directly to printer (User's Default Printer), without even opening them. Is it Possible? How?

Comment: This printer is on your server for this asp.net application and not on a client's PC, right? If so, I'm guessing a `PrintDialog` example would get you running, just omit the `ShowDialog` step.

Comment: That's the problem, I think. I need to print on User's PC Default Printer. Impossible?

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to call the print dialog? I don't think Windows lets a web application take control of the user's PC. IF that is what you want: You might have to have them install an application that allows TCP communication between his PC and your Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a bit of software called batch print pro, it will monitor a folder for a pdf dropping in, then print it out. We just schedule the reports to save to a pdf, monitor the folder with batch print pro and then this prints them out. Seems to work well